# Async/Await seems to be blocking other calls

Tags: c#, async-await

I'm new to the whole async/await part of C# and i've been banging my head against a wall for almost a full day or so now.

I'm uploading a file from my web page to another app. When they receive this file they  will begin executing some instructions that it contains (this works fine).
However, after if send the file to their server I call another of their methods which will return the progress of the execution.

The issue i'm facing here is that the GetProgress() method will only return after the UploadFile() method finishes and at that point the progress will always be 100%.

These are the methods i'm currently working with:

```
public class FileUpload : IHttpHandler
    {
    public async void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {

        HttpPostedFile uploadedfile = context.Request.Files[0];

        string FileName = uploadedfile.FileName;
        string FileType = uploadedfile.ContentType;
        int FileSize = uploadedfile.ContentLength;

       await UploadFile(uploadedfile.InputStream);
        GetProgress();

    }

         public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> UploadFile(Stream stream1)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage task = null;
            try
            {
                _importOperationId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                using (var fileStreamContent = new StreamContent(stream1))
                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    using (var formData = new MultipartFormDataContent())
                    {
                        client.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0, 0);
                        formData.Add(fileStreamContent, _importOperationId, _importOperationId + ".xml");
                        task = await client.PostAsync(systemDataServiceUrl + resource + _importOperationId, formData);
                    }
                }

            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                Logging.AddErrorLogItem(exc, _importOperationId, "Import.aspx");
            }
            return task;
        }
}
```

and the front end part:

```
    <form id="file_upload" >

    <input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" data-url="FileUpload.ashx" multiple>


    <script src="../Scripts/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        /*global $ */
        $(function () {
            $('#fileupload').fileupload({
                dataType: 'json',
                done: function (e, data) {
                    $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
                        $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo(document.body);
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated,for some reason i don't seem to be able to grasp how async/await works, even though i'm quite comfortable with AJAX.

Comment: The `await` stops your method there and returns.  The method will continue *after* that call returns.  You want to store the task for future results but not await it.

Comment: Something along these lines? `var uploadedFile= UploadFile(uploadedfile.InputStream);`

Comment: @DVM I don't think that will solve your problem either - I think you have a fundamental misunderstanding of what async/await does or is for. All await does is suspend the method until it's ready to continue (freeing up resources - normally threads - for something else... other requests in the context of web programming). It sounds like `GetProgress` should be a separate polling request.

Comment: You can put your code into a BackgroundWorker so you can report the progress while waiting for a response from server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The issue i'm facing here is that the GetProgress() method will only return after the UploadFile() method finishes and at that point the progress will always be 100%.

You can easily call `GetProgress` while the `UploadFile` is working by just not `await`ing the task right away:

```
var uploadFileTask = UploadFile(uploadedfile.InputStream);
GetProgress();
await uploadfileTask;
```

Though I don't think that you'll be able to do what I think you want to do.

> i don't seem to be able to grasp how async/await works, even though i'm quite comfortable with AJAX

One important point is that [`async` doesn't change the HTTP protocol](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/08/async-doesnt-change-http-protocol.html) (as I describe on my blog). You still only have one response for each request. It's not really possible to send progress updates as multiple responses and then the final result as another response. You may be better off using a transport that supports independent messages, such as SignalR.

Answer (score 2):

This is as intended. What `await` does is set off an asynchronous operation and then suspend the calling method until the operation is complete. Once it is, it resumes the calling method.

Sounds pointless? Yes, but the idea is that an overlying framework can at this point do something else. In ASP.NET MVC we see that when you run an async action method and `await` something, like a disc operation, another request can be handled by that thread while we wait, thus increasing concurrent availability of the system. Async event handlers in WPF can invoke asynchronous I/O which doesn't block the main render thread and improves application responsiveness without the programmer having to write explicit threading code.

The idea is to give the *illusion* of synchronous programming while gaining some of the benefits of asynchronicity in an easy-to-use manner. If you want true explicit concurrency you have to start using concurrency tools such as the Task Parallel Library (which `async`/`await` is built on in the first place) explicitly to say "go off and do this in another thread while I carry on".

Comment: No, `await` *doesn't* set off an asynchronous operation. That's purely the responsibility of another piece of code, such as methods such as `UploadFile` or `PostAsync` in the OPs code. How *those* methods achieve their results is an implementation detail, and doesn't depend upon the existence of `await`.

Comment: It calls something which returns a `Task`, then causes the calling method to wait until the `Result` of that task is available. That counts as setting of an asynchronous method in my head. What I was quite careful to say is that there is not necessarily any concurrency involved, which was the OP's confusion.

Comment: I just dislike the "set off" phrasing - you can await on any Task (or awaitable) no matter when or how it was created - it may have been created many lines before the line containing `await` or in another method, etc. `await` needs something that *has* set off already, the "setting off" is something else's responsibility.